# FormData doesn't work with String on Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, cross-browser, xmlhttprequest

I made a site web that uses ajax XmlHttpRequest of level 1 and 2. With google chrome it works. But now I'm trying with other browsers and with firefox it returns this exception message:

```
Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA) [nsIDOMFormData.append]
```

now, the code that I use is the following:

```
try {
            var sampleFile = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
            var ext = $("#file").val().substr(
                    $("#file").val().lastIndexOf(".") + 1).toLowerCase();
            if ($("#file").val() != "" && ext != "jpg" && ext != "jpeg"
                    && ext != "bmp" && ext != "png" && ext != "gif") {
                alert("Il formato dell'immagine purtroppo non è valido!\nSono ammesse immagini JPG,JPEG,GIF,PNG e BMP.");
                return;
            }

            var nomeDaPulire = document.getElementById("nome").value;

            var cognomeDaPulire = document.getElementById("cognome").value;
            var usernameDaPulire = document.getElementById("username").value;
            var pwdDaPulire = document.getElementById("password").value;
            var pwdBisDaPulire = document.getElementById("passwordBis").value;
            var anno = document.getElementById("anno").value;
            var professione = document.getElementById("comboProfessione").value;
            var città = Pulisci(document.getElementById("comboCittà").value);
            var sessoM = document.getElementById("M").checked;
            var sesso = "";
            var nome = "";
            var cognome = "";
            var username = "";
            var pwd = "";
            var pwdBis = "";
            var email = "";
            var emailDaPulire = document.getElementById("email").value;

            if (nomeDaPulire == "" 
                    || cognomeDaPulire == "" || emailDaPulire == ""
                    || pwdDaPulire == "" || pwdBisDaPulire == ""
                    || professione == "nullo" || anno == "nullo"
                    || città == "nullo") {
                alert("Riempi tutti i campi!");
                return;
            }

            if (checkSpecial(nomeDaPulire) == false
                    || checkSpecial(cognomeDaPulire) == false
                    || checkSpecialUser(usernameDaPulire) == false
                    || checkSpecialPwd(pwdDaPulire) == false
                    || checkSpecialPwd(pwdBisDaPulire) == false
                    || checkSpecialEmail(emailDaPulire) == false) {
                alert("Per favore, non inserire caratteri speciali!");
                return;
            } else {
                nome = Pulisci(nomeDaPulire);
                cognome = Pulisci(cognomeDaPulire);
                username = Pulisci(usernameDaPulire);
                pwd = Pulisci(pwdDaPulire);
                pwdBis = Pulisci(pwdBisDaPulire);
                email = Pulisci(emailDaPulire);
            }

            if (sessoM == true) {
                sesso = "M";
            } else {
                sesso = "F";
            }

            var celiaco = document.getElementById("celiaco").checked;
            if (celiaco == true)
                cel = 1;
            else
                cel = 0;

            var lattosio = document.getElementById("lattosio").checked;
            if (lattosio == true)
                lat = 1;
            else
                lat = 0;

            var animal = document.getElementById("animal").checked;
            if (animal == true)
                an = 1;
            else
                an = 0;

            var biologico = document.getElementById("bio").checked;
            if (biologico == true)
                bio = 1;
            else
                bio = 0;

            var linea = document.getElementById("linea").checked;
            if (linea == true)
                lin = 1;
            else
                lin = 0;

            var vegan = document.getElementById("vegan").checked;
            if (vegan == true)
                veg = 1;
            else
                veg = 0;

            if (pwd.localeCompare(pwdBis) == 0) {
                    d3.select("#button").remove();
                d3.select("#buttonLine").append("img").attr("id","immLoad").attr("src",
                        "imm/progressLoad.gif");
                formdata.append("username", username);
                formdata.append("pwd", pwd);
                formdata.append("nome", nome);
                formdata.append("cognome", cognome);
                formdata.append("sesso", sesso);
                formdata.append("professione", professione);
                formdata.append("anno", anno);
                formdata.append("citt", città);
                formdata.append("lattosio", lat);
                formdata.append("glutine", cel);
                formdata.append("linea", lin);
                formdata.append("vegan", veg);
                formdata.append("biologico", bio);
                formdata.append("animal", an);
                formdata.append("sampleFile", sampleFile);
                formdata.append("email", email);
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open("POST", "RegistraUtente", true);

                xhr.send(formdata);

                xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                        if (xhr.status == 200) {
                            var str = xhr.responseText;
                            if (str.length == 2) {
                                alert("lo username scelto è già in uso, per favore scegline un'altro!");
                            } else {
                                alert("la registrazione è avvenuta correttamente! Tra pochi istanti arriverà l'email con il link di conferma!");
                                window.location.href = "#login";
                            }
                        } else {
                            alert("error with the server");
                            d3.select("#immLoad").remove();
                            d3.select("#buttonLine").append("a").attr("class", "super button blue").attr("id",
                            "button").text("REGISTRATI").style("font-size", "16px").style(
                            "font-family", "GeezaPro, Calibri").on(
                            "click",
                            function() {
                                registrazione();
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
            } else {
                alert("Le due password devono coincidere!");
            }
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
            return;
        }
```

the function Pulisci is the following:

```
function Pulisci(temp){
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("è","#egrave;");
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("à","#agrave;");
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("ì","#igrave;");
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("ò","#ograve;");
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("ù","#ugrave;");
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("é","#eacuta;");
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("€","#euro;");
    temp=temp.ReplaceAll("°","#ordm;");
    return temp;
```

}

What's the problem here? why with firefox doesn't work?
Help please!!
thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to know what the problem is without knowing what the `FormData` object looks like, or what the custom `.append` function does ?

Comment: @adeneo I can't understand your comment. What do you want to know? DataForm is a Javascript object. And the method append on the object formdata apends parameters to the ajax request.

Comment: From the failure code, something seems to be wrong with the append function, and since you did'nt post the append function it's impossible for anyone to figure out what exactly could be wrong ?

Comment: but the append function is a function of the object Dataform. I did not write it.

Comment: I definitely have seen this post yesterday and revised it. Did you just delete the old one and post again?

Comment: yes but I've edited it in the appropriate way. I did it because there wasn't answers. but nothing has changed. why -1?

Comment: Cause, people commented below yesterday and you didn't reply. You are wasting everyone's time.

Comment: what you say is not true! I reply!

Comment: @user1856906 you may not know that, you have to @ somebody in your reply, otherwise nobody will get the notification. And there are thousands of unanswered question on the site, if it's not answered probably because, the question is not providing sufficient info, or the question just that hard, that no one can answer. But after all, delete and re-post is not the way to get your question to be answered.

Comment: and now I have to comment this again. I have asked you to provide the *line number* of the error and indicating which line of your code caused the problem.

Comment: @xiaoyi there are also people who respond with arrogance while not knowing anything about the subject. what can I say?
I'm sorry if I did not put the @ in my comments. It 's the only thing I can apologize.

Comment: @xiaoyi and I yesterday I said that I do not have a clear number line because it is the message that comes out nell'alert. Probably the error is in the sampleFile but, also yesterday, I said that with chrome this works. But no one has reply.

Comment: Yep, I didn't receive the notification. If you pay just a little more attention to the FAQ, you will know the @ thing. Back to the problem, I have tested your code yesterday on firefox, nothing goes wrong, even the line appending `File`. So please update your code with a complete version or with more context.

Comment: Here is the problem. remove your `try`, and let browser to catch it.

Comment: @xiaoyi. I've done. It's a lot of code but I post it entirely because I don't know where is the problem. The code enter in the catch and shows the alert.

Comment: @xiaoyi. ok, without the try catch firefox doesn't do anything.

Comment: @user1856906 check your console (ctrl+shift+k), or install firebug to get the error info.

Comment: @xiaoyi: --
[14:10:45.290] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA) [nsIDOMFormData.append]"  nsresult: "0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)"  location: "JS frame :: http://127.0.0.1:8080/Tesi/javascript/Home.js :: registrazione :: line 1533"  data: no]

the line 1533 id the first .append

Comment: @user1856906 good, now we know the line number, so what's in that line?

Comment: @xiaoyi:formdata.append("username", username);

Comment: set a breakpoint on that line, or add console.log(username) before that to see what's in the `username`

Comment: and what is `Pulisci()`???

Comment: @xiaoyi Pulisci is a function that replace some letters of the strings. I edit my question and I write it.

Comment: @user1856906 and what's the value of `username`? try put `console.log(typeof username, encodeURIComponent(username), username);` before your first append. lets see what's inside.

Comment: @xiaoyi: I put the console.log(username) --
[14:21:38.507] (new String("prova")) @ http://127.0.0.1:8080/Tesi/javascript/Home.js:1533
[14:21:38.508] uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA) [nsIDOMFormData.append]"  nsresult: "0x80460001 (NS_ERROR_CANNOT_CONVERT_DATA)"  location: "JS frame :: http://127.0.0.1:8080/Tesi/javascript/Home.js :: registrazione :: line 1534"  data: no]

Comment: @xiaoyi the result is this: --
[14:24:14.845] object hhhh (new String("hhhh")) @ http://127.0.0.1:8080/Tesi/javascript/Home.js:1533

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great, finally got sufficient information to fix your problem, you missed almost all the important things in your question.

According to [specs](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/xhr/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#interface-formdata) `FormData` only works with `Blob` or `DOMString`. Which means it won't work with `String` which is an `Object` instead of literal `string`.

As Mozilla [indicated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData), it works with `Blob`, `File` and `string`, otherwise, it will perform a force conversion to `string`. But somehow, `String` instance failed to be converted automatically (I think you should file it in [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=FormData+String),) which throws the error.

Two possible fixes:

- Stop using `new String()`, when assign a literal string to a variable will automatically create a new one.
- Force the conversion by your self, using `username.toString()`, and you will need to do this for all your text fields.

PS:

You probably should not use Unicode variable names, though it is fine with javascript. But looks strange. And the actual name of this question should be *FormData doesn't work with String on Firefox*.

Comment: now it works! thank you very much xiaoyi.
With you today I learned lot of things:
-first of all: never delete and rewrite your questions :P
-use @ in the comment to have users notifications. :P
-that I can use ctrl+shift+K to have a console in the browser
-I have a very good answer for my question. THANKS! :)

Comment: @user1856906 if possible, file it on bugzilla, other people may run into the same problem.

Comment: I give you permission to do it for me if you want.I should learn how to use bugzilla. :)

Comment: @user1856906 you may want to subscribe to the [ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=776539), in case it fixed someday.