# Ajax sends empty POST-data but ONLY in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a strange problem (which I've searched for but with no success). I'm using Ajax to post a form to a PHP-script. This works fine in Chrome, Opera and Safari. However, in both IE and Firefox the form gets sent to the script correctly but with the form data missing. When the POST-data is missing, I've made sure that the script returns an error. I've tried to search for this problem for hours, but without any luck. You're my last hope.

Here's the AJAX code (with some Javascript):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#latestNewsForm").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url         : "http://devserver/site/php/getLatestArticles.php",
        type        : "POST",
        data        : new FormData(this),
        contentType : false,
        cache       : false,
        processData : false
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#formResponse").html(data);
    });

   });
  });
  </script>
```

And here's the form:

```
<form id="latestNewsForm"  method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="currentPage" id="firstPage" value="1">
</form>
```

A BIG thanks in advance!

Comment: `FormData(this)` this is why.

Comment: So, what should I replace data: new FormData(this) with and why is it working in Chrome, Opera and Safari? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ohgodwhy's comment is likely correct.

Put your data in a variable outside that ajax call. `this` is probably referring to something different than you expect in different browsers.

Try this:

```
$("#latestNewsForm").on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var data = new FormData(this);

    $.ajax({
        url         : "http://devserver/site/php/getLatestArticles.php",
        type        : "POST",
        data        : data,
        contentType : false,
        cache       : false,
        processData : false
    }).done(function (data) {
        $("#formResponse").html(data);
    });

   });
```

Another possibility could be related to your submit button: [Submit rollover button not working in FF and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19335015/submit-rollover-button-not-working-in-ff-and-ie)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Putting the data in a variable outside the Ajax call didn't solve the problem. I use Bootstrap 3 on my site, however the submit button doesn't utilize Bootstrap (i.e. it's a standard submit button).

Comment: can you go in firebug, put a breakpoint inside this function, and step through to see if it executes the ajax call correctly and that the data object is what you expect?

Comment: I've never user Firebug. However, I created a custom form data by using:

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('currentPage', '1');

This worked in all browsers. So there's definitely something wrong with the form data in IE and Firefox. :/

Comment: also maybe check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762424/formdata-doesnt-work-with-string-on-firefox

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/fetchdata",
    data:JSON.stringify(sid),
    success: function(result) {
        alert('ok');
    },
    error: function(result) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```